# Select from cursor

Tags: mysql, loop, cursor

Estou tentando fazer uma procedure com o seguinte bloco mysql:

```
DECLARE done         INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE v_id         INT;
DECLARE R CURSOR FOR 
                            SELECT  id                                     
                                   ,nome
                              FROM pessoa d                               

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
OPEN R;
 read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH R INTO v_id;
      IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
      END IF;

      SELECT DATE_FORMAT(previsao,'%d/%m/%Y') as doba_dt_previsao
                             ,usuario_id
                         FROM documentos 
                        WHERE doc_pess_id = (

                                        SELECT MAX(doc_ID) ID
                                         FROM DOCUMENTOS
                                        WHERE doc_pess_id = v_id
                       )

                       AND docu_quitr IS NULL
                       AND previsao < DATE(NOW()) 
    END LOOP;
  CLOSE R;
```

Gostaria de saber se tem mostrar só valores do select de dentro do loop, num único select.

Porque eu entendo que, toda vez que ele rodar o loop ele vai fazer o select, gostaria saber se tem como ele guardar esses valores do loop em uma variável para depois então eu mostrar?

Não sei se seria correto dar um **select de um cursor**

Criar outro cursor dentro do loop para mostrar?

É porque eu pesquisei, não sei se pesquisei direito, mas não achei

Comment: Veja aqui. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE email_list_temp_table (in w_uf varchar(2))
BEGIN
   DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE v_email varchar(100) DEFAULT ""; 
   DECLARE v_telefone varchar(100) DEFAULT ""; 
   DEClARE clientes_cursor CURSOR FOR
       SELECT email,telefone FROM clientes where uf=w_uf order by nome; 
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;
   create temporary table temp_table (email varchar(100),telefone varchar(100));   
   OPEN clientes_cursor;
   get_dados: LOOP
       FETCH clientes_cursor INTO v_email,v_telefone;
       IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
           LEAVE get_dados;
       END IF;
       insert into temp_table (email,telefone) values (v_email,v_telefone);
   END LOOP get_dados;
   CLOSE clientes_cursor;
   select * from temp_table;
   drop temporary table temp_table;
END$$

-- para rodar a procedure:
call email_list_temp_table('PR');
```

Answer (score 0):

Exemplo de cursor.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE build_email_list (INOUT email_list varchar(4000))
BEGIN

 DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE v_email varchar(100) DEFAULT "";

 -- declare cursor for employee email
 DEClARE email_cursor CURSOR FOR 
 SELECT email FROM employees;

 -- declare NOT FOUND handler
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

 OPEN email_cursor;

 get_email: LOOP

 FETCH email_cursor INTO v_email;

 IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
 LEAVE get_email;
 END IF;

 -- build email list
 SET email_list = CONCAT(v_email,";",email_list);

 END LOOP get_email;

 CLOSE email_cursor;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: o resultado ficaria igual a um select? Eu poderia dar depois um `select email_list` ?

Comment: Não. A ordem de execução é a seguinte: cria as variaveis, cria o cursor, abre o cursor, incia o loop, atribui às variavies o que esta na linha do cursor atraves do FETCH, faz o que tem de ser feito em função das variaveis, volta ao inicio do loop, pega as novas variaveis....até o final do cursor e finalmente fecha o cursor.

Comment: Isso!! Agora depois de todo o loop gostaria de mostrar o resultado, no caso do exemplo da resposta acima o `email_cursor` como se fosse um resultado de um select

Comment: Eu acho que você não entendeu e eu não estou entendo o que você quer. O email_cursor contem os campos e valores do select  SELECT email FROM employees como ele foi declarado. Digamos que você precisa fazer alguma coisa em função desses emails. Você declara o cursor, percorre todos os seus registros e fecha. Se você que o resultado do cursor, você simplesmente não precisa dele, você faz o select e pronto.

Comment: dentro do loop tem outro select, eu quero juntar todos os resultados do select do loop em um unico no final

Comment: Não é para isso que serve um cursor, nem existe essa possibilidade. Você deve junta-los fazendo um JOIN entre as tabelas e não um cursor.